# relist a data.frame object & append it in existing list by order

Tags: r, list, dataframe, reshape2

I have one set of data.frame objects and one single data.frame objects. I am trying to put them together in the list by order. I tried unlist to do this sort of manipulation, but it won't yield correct output at the end. Can anyone give me possible ideas to do this? Thanks a lot

## simulated data:

```
bleh <- data.frame(
  start=seq(1, by=9, len=18), end=seq(6, by=9, len=18),
  ID=letters[seq(1:18)], score=sample(1:25, 18, replace = FALSE))

d.list <- list(
  foo <- data.frame(
    start=seq(2, by=11, len=20), end=seq(8, by=11, len=20),
    ID=letters[seq(1:20)], score=sample(1:25, 20, replace = FALSE)),
  bar <- data.frame(
    start=seq(4, by=11, len=25), end=seq(9, by=11, len=25),
    ID=letters[seq(1:25)], score=sample(1:25, 25, replace = FALSE))
)
```

## desired output:

```
out <- list(blesh, d.list[1], d.list[2])
```

If I flatted the d.list and reshape all object in the list, it is not correct by concept, because unlist method will flatten d.list as one object, that's I stop this things happen. Does any one know the trick of doing this kind of manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concatenation` method `c` after wrapping the single data frame object into a list. `c` when applied to lists will flatten lists at the first level and then concatenate the sublists together, which should give you what you need.

```
out <- c(list(bleh), d.list)

lapply(out, head, 3)
# [[1]]
#   start end ID score
# 1     1   6  a    16
# 2    10  15  b    18
# 3    19  24  c     7

# [[2]]
#   start end ID score
# 1     2   8  a    23
# 2    13  19  b     1
# 3    24  30  c    16

# [[3]]
#   start end ID score
# 1     4   9  a    16
# 2    15  20  b     8
# 3    26  31  c    10
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This trick certainly works very well. Cheers

Comment: @user88911 No problems. Glad it helps. :)